# AWS Quicksight - get std dev for fields grouped by sum?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

New to QS. I have data like this:

| timestamp | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 5 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2 |
| 2022-01-02 | 0 |
| 2022-01-02 | 9 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2 |

I want to sum the counts for each timestamp, and then get the standard deviation for those sums.

My attempt was this, because a similar approach worked for getting the median:

```
stdev(sumOver({count}, [timestamp], PRE_AGG))
```

Resulting value is always a little lower than it should be(for example 13.53 instead of 15.03). What's wrong?

Comment: Is it just because of the stdev formula? If you use `sqrt(N - 1)` in the denominator, while Quicksight use `sqrt(N)`, they will get a slightly lower number. I don't know if Quicksight does, just suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Register Sole it is probably the difference between the standard deviation of the sample, `stdev` in Quicksight which uses `sqrt(N-1)` and the standard deviation of the population, `stdevp` in Quicksight, which uses `sqrt(N)` as the denominator in the standard deviation formula.

Using your sample provided above I made the Quicksight Table visualisation below without any calculated fields, just adding the `count` field multiple times and changing the aggregation used for the column:

[image]

I confirmed the stdevs in both Excel and manually as accurate. Cheers (I would have added this as a comment but lack the rep)